# PHP change button text and update database accordingly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How my function works:
There are 2 buttons 'Accept' and 'Decline'. When user clicks on Accept, the text will change to 'Accepted' and both buttons will be disabled. Colour of text changes too. After this process, i need to update the database table column accordingly.

My current situation:
I'm showing more than one entry with this function.
Currently my codes only work when i have one entry and it doesn't stays the way it should be when I pressed on it after I refresh the page. When there are more than one entry, the button i clicked on the second entry somehow detects the first entry and changes the button in the first entry. **And i have no clue on how to update the database accordingly.**

Thank You so much in advance.

My Script:

```
<script>
        function accept() {
            document.getElementById("accept").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("decline").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("accept").innerHTML = 'Accepted';
            document.getElementById("accept").style.color = "green";

        }

        function decline() {
            document.getElementById("decline").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("accept").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("decline").innerHTML = 'Declined';
            document.getElementById("decline").style.color = "red";
        }
    </script>
```

Accept Button:

```
<button id="accept" onclick="accept()">Accept</button>
```

Decline Button:

```
<button id="decline" onclick="decline()">Decline</button>
```

Comment: use js between `window.onload=function(){}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to use AJAX:
Using JQuery AJAX makes it much easier.
JS FILE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/updateDatabase.php";
    type: "POST";
    data: {update: value},
    beforeSend: function (){
       //stuff you like to do before sending.
    }
    success: function (data){
       //do something with return data
    }

});
```

PHP FILE: updateDatabase.php

```
$var = $_POST["update"]; //make sure this is the same name for the data{} json string
//update database.

echo "Put return value here for JS success data var."
```

Remember Button state:

```
<?php if(databaseValue == Accepted) { ?>
      <button>Format Button Disabled for accepted</button>

<?php } else { ?>
      <button>Format button for enabled</button>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing two functions if 50% of the operations of the functions are same. I suggest you to write only one function and put a conditional statement in it which checks which button was clicked. It is efficient programming!

Regarding your question can you share a screenshot here, as what exactly is displayed when the operation is performed.